# Edit a Model with an input. ValueError

Tags: python, html, django

Trying to allow the user to edit a decimal value 'amount'. When a user clicks on 'edit', a decimal field shows up. When the user is finished changing the value and clicks "done"...

It throws this error:

`Exception Type: ValueError`
`Exception Value: Cannot use None as a query value`

Here is my template:

```
<form class="nice input-prepend edit-allocation-form" action="/portfolio/edit/" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input class="input-text required number" type="text" name="edit_amount{{ investment.position.id }}" {% if investment.position.amount %}value="{{ investment.position.amount }}"{% endif %}>

     <a href="#" class="edit" id="edit{{ investment.position.id }}">edit</a>
     <button class="hide" type="submit" id="saveAmountButton"></button>
</form>
```

And here is my view:

```
@login_required
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       profile = get_object_or_404(InvestorProfile, user=request.user)
       position = InvestorPosition.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.get('id'))
       if Decimal(request.POST['edit_amount' + str(position.id)]) != position.amount:
            position.amount = Decimal(request.POST['edit_amount' + str(position.id)])
            position.save()                
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', '/portfolio/'))
```

I can't make this work. Help a noob out?

Comment: Does `request.POST.get('id')` return something (that's not `None`)? I do not see your form somewhere setting an `id` field?

Comment: You should have posted that as the answer because it's correct.  Unless he's got some JS he's decided to not show then the id is never getting posted, so of course it's returning None

Comment: I'd also like to add this code has a multitude of other issues.  Using <button> instead of <input type="submit"...> is silly, id__in=request.POST.get('id')) is wrong unless you're somehow making it into a list, why isn't this just using a django ModelForm?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using <button type="submit" />. It's much easier to use than <input type="submit" />. It does look like the op is hiding the button and doing some javascript trickery in order to submit the form though. That's a bad idea.

Comment: @nijansen <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ investment.position.id }}" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the above commenter said, the form isn't posting any field named "id". What you want is "edit_amount{{ id }}".

Here's an example of how to extract the ID from the form field name. It's lacking [exception catching](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and some other "gotchas" you'll want to lookout for. But this is the basic idea.

I do suggest that you add a [hidden form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput) with the ID instead of doing it this way though. You should also [check the permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#permissions) of the user, and make sure that they're able to modify that specific record.

```
@login_required
def edit(request):
   # Skipping the first couple lines.
   id = None
   for key in request.POST.keys():
       if 'edit_amount' in key:
           id = int(key[11:])

   position = InvestorPosition.objects.get(id=id)

   position.amount = Decimal(request.POST.get('edit_amount%s' % id))
   position.save()

   return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', '/portfolio/'))
```

Comment: This was very helpful thank you. After adding a hidden input, the error no longer appears.